# Merging ND array into single array and list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

What I have is:

```
x = array([a, a, a, a, a, a],
          [b, b, b, b, b, b],
          [................],
          [z,z,z,z,z,z,z,z,])
```

I am looking for a way about:

i. How to covert this array into a 1D array x = array[a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,b,b,b,b,b,..,z,z,z] and a 1D list x = [a,a,a,a,a,a,a,b,b,b,b,b,...,z,z,z].

ii. Calculating the exact dimensions of this array: I tried len(x[0]) and len(x) to get the both dimensional coordinates, but this way seems a bit hackish. Is there any built-in function to get the dimensions of an array?

Note: some of the array values are positive integers, some of them are floats, some of them are negative floats, and some of them are negative integers.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `np.ravel` for this task.
Just call the list constructor if that's how you want output.
`.shape` will give you the number of rows and columns, respectively, but you don't actually need to know them.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.random.random_integers(0, 9, (3, 4))
>>> a.shape
(3, 4)
>>> print a
[[9 5 1 8]
 [3 1 3 1]
 [3 9 6 6]]
>>> a.ravel()
array([9, 5, 1, 8, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 9, 6, 6])
>>> list(a.ravel())
[9, 5, 1, 8, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 9, 6, 6]
```

Comment: This works! fine. All I had to do is to have some modifications with the files and apply the np.ravel(). I am done. Thanks a million. :-)

Comment: There is also `.flat`, which is just an iterator but enough for such purpose. The advantage is that `.ravel()` may have to create a copy of the data. It doesn't matter for you I am sure, but it can be a nice feature.

Answer (score 1):

To create a 1D array from an ND array, use `ndarray.flatten()`

```
x = array([a, a, a, a, a, a],
      [b, b, b, b, b, b],
      [................],
      [z,z,z,z,z,z,z,z,])
x.flatten()
```

To get a list from this, use `ndarray.tolist()`

```
xlist = x.tolist()
```

To get the dimensions of an array, use `ndarray.shape`

```
print x.shape
(4, 6)
```

Comment: for 1D list, you probably want `x.flatten().tolist()`

Comment: working with flatten simply allocates every tuple into a single array. I need a single array like x = [a,a,a,a...z,z,z,z] which lists everything from that multi-dimensional array into a serialized format. :-(

Answer (score 1):

- To transform the 2D array as a 1D array, you can use `np.ravel(a)`. If you want to do so *in place*, you can also use `a.shape=-1`. The `a.flatten` method will return a *copy* of the initial array, which is wasteful.
- To transform your 1D array into a list, you can use `list(a)` or `a.tolist()`. To transform your 2D array into a flat list, the simpler by far is `list(a.flat)` (`.flat` returns a 'flat' iterator). Note that using `a.tolist` on a 2D array will give you a list of list, while using `list(a)` will give you a list of arrays.
- Use `a.shape` to get the sizes of `a` along each dimension, as a tuple with as many elements as dimensions. Note that `len(a)==a.shape[0]`. With your 2D array, `len(a[0])=a.shape[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Merge arrays into a new array :

```
newArray = array()
for y in x
  newArray += y
```

find length :

```
len(newArray)
```

Comment: To create a 1D array use `ndarray.flatten()`

Comment: gabitzish and Vorticity: both of the methods are not working. I want to get a single array like array[a,a,a,a,...z,z,z,z] without any objects or tuples in them. Just a serialized list. It's not happening with the methods you guys specified.